# shell string and program execute

Tags: linux, shell

The following code is used to create a file in exactly location.However result of running test.sh abc is

> touch: missing file operand

```
#! /bin/sh
#test.sh
location='~/configuration/'$1
echo $location
touch `$location`
```

Is there anything wrong?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By putting `$location` in backticks, you're trying to *execute* the value of `$location` and use that as the argument to `touch` (see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html), section 3.4.5) Just do:

```
touch $location
```

If you run `#!/bin/sh` with the `-x` value, you'll see more clearly what `bash` is doing in your shell script. It's a very useful means to debug scripts.

Comment: However,by removing backticks,result is:touch: cannot touch `~/configuration/abc': No such file or directory

Comment: Does `~/configuration` exist as a directory? `touch` will create a file if necessary, but it won't create the directory structure named by the file - it expects the directories to already be there.

Comment: "$location" should be quoted. This is especially important when providing examples to beginners who do not yet understand how bash performs word-splitting.

Answer (score 2):

When you put `~` in quotes, it loses its special meaning. You need:

```
#! /bin/sh
#test.sh
location=~/configuration/"$1"
echo "$location"
touch "$location"
```

You should get into the habit of always putting variables in double quotes (until you learn the specific times when you don't want quotes).

Answer (score 2):

Is location a folder or file ?
if file -f if folder -d in below script  --- bash should understand ~

```
#! /bin/bash
#test.sh
var1=$1;
location=~/configuration/$var1
echo $location

if [ ! -f $location ]; then
 echo "not found touching $location"
 touch `$location`
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but the first fix is to change to

```
touch `echo $location`
```

However I think it might be simpler to do

```
touch ~/configuration/$1
```

Comment: Using the backticks instead of just `touch "$location"` forks a process for no real reason at all.